# A* pathfinding find path that player need to walk, c++ in Qt

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt

I'm trying to implement the A* algorithm for finding the fastest path to the destination. I can find the path when the destination is not far away from the player. But it's freezes when I take a position that is far away from the player. Can anyone help me out with this? Can't find it anyway.

```
int Controller::findPathfindingNodes(int xdes, int ydes)
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tile>> tiles = model->getAllLimitTiles(); //all the tiles where we can move
    std::shared_ptr<Protagonist> prota = model->getAllProtagonist(); //get data from protagonist
    int currentX = prota->getXPos(); //get xpos of prota
    int currentY = prota->getYPos(); //get ypos of prota

    openList.clear();
    closedList.clear();
    mylist.clear();

    //return 50;
    std::shared_ptr<Tile> endPoint = model->getCoordinate(QPointF(xdes,ydes));
    std::shared_ptr<Tile> startPoint = model->getCoordinate(QPointF(currentX,currentY));
    int sumtotal = abs((currentX - xdes) + (currentY - ydes));

    //we insert our start position, we have no parrent yet
    PathFinding* start = new PathFinding(startPoint,currentX, currentY, 0, sumtotal,nullptr);
    //this value we insert in our openList
    openList.insert(start->getXCoord() + (model->getCols()+1)*start->getYCoord(), start);

    bool pathFound = false;
    int i = 0;
    int pathcost;
    //do whil path is found
    while(!pathFound){
        QHashIterator<int, PathFinding*> iterator(openList);
        PathFinding* parent;
        iterator.next();
        parent = iterator.value();
        //we take the next tile, and we take the one with the lowest value
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            iterator.next();
            //checking lowest f value
            if((iterator.value()->getGcost() + iterator.value()->getHcost()) < (parent->getGcost() + parent->getHcost())){
                parent = iterator.value();
            }
        }
        //here we check if we are at the destionation. if we are we return our pathcost.
        if(atDestionation(parent,endPoint)){
            pathFound = true;
            while(parent->hasParent()){
                 mylist.append(parent);
                 parent = parent->getParent();
            }

            //we calculate what the pathcost is and return it
            pathcost = calculatePathCost(mylist);
            return pathcost;
        }else{
            int parent_x = parent->getXCoord();
            int parent_y = parent->getYCoord();
            i++;
            clearLists(parent);
            filllists(parent,endPoint);
        }
     }
}
```

To put the values of the nodes in the open & closed list I do with this:

```
void Controller::filllists(PathFinding *parent,std::shared_ptr<Tile> endPoint)
{

    int xPosNode = parent->getXPos();
    int yPosNode = parent->getYPos();
    //while found location
    for(int x = -1; x < 2; x++) {
        for(int y = -1; y <2; y++) {
            int p_x = xPosNode + x;
            int p_y = yPosNode + y;
             // Is this coordinate within the world?
             if(p_x >= 0 && p_x < model->getCols() && p_y >= 0 && p_y < model->getRows()) {
                 //we check if the tile exist (if it's no infinity tile)
                 if(model->tileExist(QPointF(p_x,p_y))){
                     // Already in open list > Check if current node is a better parent
                     if((!openList.value(p_x))+ (model->getCols() + 1)*(p_y)){
                         // Not in open and not in closed list > Possible candidate
                         if((!closedList.value(p_x))+ (model->getCols() + 1)*(p_y)){
                             int h_value = calculateHvalue(parent->getXCoord(),parent->getYCoord(),endPoint->getXPos(),endPoint->getYPos());
                             //int g_value = parent->getGcost() + calculateTileCost(parent->getXCoord(),parent->getYCoord(),p_x,p_y);
                             int g_value = calculateGvalue(parent, p_x,  p_y);
                             std::shared_ptr<Tile> tile = model->getCoordinate(QPointF(p_x,p_y));
                             PathFinding* move = new PathFinding(tile,p_x, p_y, g_value, h_value, parent);
                             int number = move->getXCoord() + (model->getCols()+1)*move->getYCoord();
                             openList.insert(move->getXCoord() + (model->getCols()+1)*move->getYCoord(), move);
                         }
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My header file looks like:

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Controller(std::shared_ptr<Model> &modelPtr,std::shared_ptr<View> &viewPtr);
   // void checkTile(QString position,PathFinding *parent, std::shared_ptr<Tile> endPoint, int pos);
    void checkAboveTile(PathFinding *parent, std::shared_ptr<Tile> endPoint, int pos);
    void checkBelowTile(PathFinding *parent, std::shared_ptr<Tile> endPoint, int pos);
    void checkLeftTile(PathFinding *parent,  std::shared_ptr<Tile> endPoint, int pos);
    void checkRightTile(PathFinding *parent, std::shared_ptr<Tile> endPoint, int pos);
    bool atDestionation(PathFinding *parent, std::shared_ptr<Tile> endPoint);
    float calculateTileCost(int xposnew,int yposnew, int xpos, int ypos);
    int calculateHvalue(int p_x,int p_y, int des_x, int des_y);
    int calculateGvalue(PathFinding *parent, int x, int y);
    void filllists(PathFinding *parent, std::shared_ptr<Tile> endPoint);

    //QPair<QList<QPointF>, float> generatePath(Tile* endPoint);
    //Openlist contains the nodes to be examined
    QHash <int, PathFinding *> openList;
    //ClosedList has the nodes that are already examined
    QHash <int, PathFinding *> closedList;
    QList<QPointF> pathlist;
    void clearLists(PathFinding *parent);
    QList<PathFinding*> mylist;
    int calculatePathCost(QList<PathFinding*> mylist);
    int findPathfindingNodes(int xdes, int ydes);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Model> model;
    std::shared_ptr<View> view;
    int heurCost;
signals:
    void atDestination(int xPos,int yPos);
    void gotoview(int xPos,int yPos);
public slots :
    void goToDestination(int xDestination, int yDestination);


};

#endif // CONTROLLER_H
```

When I try to output the path which is travelled the I can see that it put sometimes the same position in mylist.

```
X1 value : 2 Y1 value : 3 
X1 value : 1 Y1 value : 3 
X1 value : 0 Y1 value : 3 
X1 value : 1 Y1 value : 3 
X1 value : 1 Y1 value : 3 
X1 value : 2 Y1 value : 3 
X1 value : 2 Y1 value : 4 
X1 value : 3 Y1 value : 4 
X1 value : 3 Y1 value : 4 
X1 value : 3 Y1 value : 5 
X1 value : 2 Y1 value : 6 
X1 value : 2 Y1 value : 6 
X1 value : 1 Y1 value : 6 
X1 value : 0 Y1 value : 6 
X1 value : 0 Y1 value : 7 
X1 value : 0 Y1 value : 6 
X1 value : 0 Y1 value : 5
```

This is how the player walked, can see that he sometimes uses the same parent over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I can't see anywhere that you move visited nodes from the open list to the closed list.
   This would account for visiting the same place multiple times.
2. `if((!openList.value(p_x)) + (model->getCols() + 1)*(p_y))` is very likely to be true.
   (Adding 0 or 1 to `(model->getCols() + 1)*p_y` is probably non-zero.)
   I believe you meant `if(!openList.value(p_x + (model->getCols() + 1)*p_y))`.
   (Same issue with the closed list.)
   This would also account for multiple visits, as you repeatedly insert the same nodes in the open list.

I would suggest abstracting out the index calculation:

```
int index(shared_ptr<Model> model, int x, int y)
{
    return x * (model->getCols() + 1)* y;
}
```

and using that instead of error-prone code reproduction, e.g.

```
openList.insert(index(model, start->getXCoord(), start->getYCoord()), start);
// ...
if(!openList.value(index(model, p_x, p_y)))
```

It's also a good idea to add tracing output along the way.